# TideSDK tutorial?

Tags: titanium, tidesdk

Is there an actual [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) tutorial that is not a remnant of the old Titanium Desktop? I can't seem to locate any clear tutorial that outlines coding to testing to building on TideSDK. Most of the things I've seen are intended to be used for the late Titanium Desktop. If anyone can outline the app creation process of TideSDK, it would be more than welcome. (E.g. Code, compile test? / Code, test, compile?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downloads from the TideSDK.org site currently provide Titanium Desktop 1.2.0.RC4 in the interim while the TideSDK Team continues to prepare for the upcoming 1.3.0-beta release (that is expected quite soon). Therefore, the legacy documentation from Appcelerator can still be used for getting you started on your desktop projects today. If you run into any issues there are friendly people on our mailing list to help. The only change in the API for 1.3.0 will be the change in the namespace from 'Titanium' to 'Ti'. Please consider joining the TideSDK mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tidesdk for assistance or follow us on Twitter http://twitter.com/tidesdk to keep up to date on TideSDK news and announcements.

Keep in mind we've been working through a transition with the legacy code and materials. It is a significant effort to assemble a capable and dedicated team, work through the complex code base, set up continuous integration infrastructure and organize the efforts the team is currently engaged in. Our repository on Github has grown from a couple of repositories to 48 over the past few months. The team is continuing to clean and organize the code that we inherited from Appcelerator so that it is possible to build upon it for the future. We are also striving to become a non profit organization as funding to support the team of 16 programmers, developers and UI designers and for the infrastructure we need for such the project. This is an important key to our success for the future.

The TideSDK team has been putting substantial effort into high quality documentation under the direction of Christian Engel, our Developer Education Lead, in anticipation of the upcoming release. TideSDK's documentation consists of API docs together with a series of Guides. A Guide is focused on a particular topic. In some cases, Guides serve as focused tutorials. To view the documentation under development, visit the brand new tidesdk.org site (launched at the end of August 2012) and click on the docs button. In the short term, the effort has been on API docs and code examples. This effort will shift to Guides quite soon.

No new features will be added for the 1.3.0-beta release but it will provide updates to the underlying libraries. This will enable the SDK to compile and be used on OSX Lion, OSX Mountain Lion, Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 and 8. Scripting language versions are being brought up to date also. Perhaps the most significant thing it will upgrade the WebKit to the lastest available. This will mean the most current HTML5 support available.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I am looking for a decent tutorial on getting started with TideSDK is because I have started working with Titanium Desktop at the time when they already have Titanium Studio. Meaning, I don't know how to do anything without the Studio but I guess the TideSDK will transition away from that trend already and I thought I should be acquainted with the newer method of working with a TIdeSDK project. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: For example, ths tutorial http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started talks about Titanium Developer, as far as I know, this is the first iteration of Titanium Studio. And Titanium Developer is something I have no experience with. It doesn't talk about the package contents of the zip file I downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: A collection of getting started resources is found at https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide

Comment: I have download from Github, and got this file `desktopsdk-1.2.0.RC4-win32.zip` but where is the executable file? There are 3 folders inside it. 
- modules
- runtime
- sdk

inside sdk I found sdk\win32\1.2.0.RC4 and kboot.exe
I think that's only executable file, when I click on it, 
returned error 
`error: application packaging error: no manifest was found at tideskd\sdk\win32... etc`

Answer (score 4):

TideSDK-1.3.1-beta is available. Please use this the most recent version of TideSDK found here

http://tidesdk.org

and refer to the Getting Started Guide located at:

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

Comment: Yeah, I follow you guys on Twitter. :) So far so good. I just wished there was an option to let the developers deploy apps with unbundled runtime that will work. Deploying 30mb of apps each and everytime can be quite a downer for a simple Notepad application :P